Parents doing palm reading will affect our life
Assalamy alaikum.My father is meeting someone and he is doing something. My father is asking him about my future and similar things. If something is bad, he asks him to remove it. I don't know what he is doing. I think it's something related to astrology or talking with jinn. My father knows that it's haram to do these kinds of things, but he is doing this to make our future better. I don't know how to tell him to stop this. Also, I have been jobless for 1 year, and everything I try leads to failure. I always think that my father doing these kinds of palm reading things is stopping me from getting a job, which is actually haram. I don't know what to do. How can I stay away from this, and how can I ensure that palm reading doesn't affect my life?"

@UmH your link covers only what should or can be done if family does things that are haram. In the question posted I see two more aspects: is "palm reading" really haram, why and to what extend (a doctor feeling your pulse surly is not haram), and then, if it is harmful how to get out of it?
